# Is there a way to override a doReturn in Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to run a method even though in @Before I set

```
doReturn(mockResult).when(spyObject).getResult();
```

It makes sense to do that for all of my other test methods, but I want to test the getter and setter for result now. Is there a way to override the doReturn and force it to actually run the method, or should I just move the doReturn statement to the beginning of every test method?

Comment: you want to execute the real method of the mocked object ?

Comment: For Mockito to work properly, you need to mock the object and use the mocked object. So once mocked, you won't be able to access to the "real" methods of your objects.

Comment: On a more personal point of view, tests for getters and setters should never been written as they are generated by your favorite IDE.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the Object I'm referring to is a spy.

Comment: Also, can JDeveloper write tests for my getters and setters? I know eclipse can, but I have to use JDeveloper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using callRealMethod

```
when(mock.someMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();
```